# What does .encodeABI() mean?

Tags: solidity

Does someone know what the .encodeABI() means on this the below line of code please?:

const data = electionContract.methods.vote(1).encodeABI()

Thank you

Take care

Pierre

Comment: The encoded ABI of the transaction denoted by `electionContract.methods.vote(1)`.

Comment: That's what is passed to the data parameter when signing a transaction to execute the "vote" function with the input parameter "1".

Comment: thank you very much goodvibration and clement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encodes the ABI for that method. The resulting hex string is 32-bit function signature hash plus the passed parameters in Solidity tightly packed format. This can be used to send a transaction, call a method, or pass it into another smart contract’s method as arguments. Set the data field on web3.eth.sendTransaction options as the encodeABI() result and it is the same as calling the contract method with contract.myMethod.send().

Some use cases for encodeABI() include: preparing a smart contract transaction for a multisignature wallet, working with offline wallets and cold storage and creating transaction payload for complex smart contract proxy calls.

REF: [web3js-documentation-->methods-mymethod-encodeabi](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html?highlight=encodeABI#methods-mymethod-encodeabi)

To learn more: [what-exactly-does-encodeabi-from-web3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29173/what-exactly-does-encodeabi-from-web3)